# Event ID 7036 Not showing the Username (N/A), how to find Username for this events?

Tags: windows, windows-server

Event ID 7036 Not showing the username and show N/A for user field in Service Stop and Start events.
Is there any needed configuration?
Is there any other solution to find who stopped/started a service?

Comment: You need to enable auditing via Group Policies. That may help going forward (check the policy requirements) but will not be retroactive.

Comment: Can you name the related Group Policy?

Comment: Try this:  Navigate to Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy.
In the left pane, expand Local Policies, and then click Audit Policy.
Select Audit object access in the right pane, and then click Action > Properties.   This is where you need to look.